# how to keep the time up-to-date in a localtime() variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to update localtime() variable I made.

```
import time
time = time.localtime()

print(time)
```

the output is 
time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=6, tm_hour=15, tm_min=34, tm_sec=48, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=126, tm_isdst=1)

I expect it to be the current time.

Comment: It is the current time. Are you just having trouble with the format?  Or ... ?  There's no problem to solve here.

Comment: `localtime()` is a function, not a variable. Every time you call `localtime()` it will return an updated value—which it the proper way to update its value.

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is [```datetime.now()```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Answer (score 2):

> I expect it to be the current time.

It is (or was) the current time -- *at the moment when you called `localtime()`*.  But that moment is now in the past.

If you want to have the current time as of right now, call `localtime()` again.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want.  Avoid using 'time' as variable because it is also a function name.  Visit this link for more formatting codes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime

```
import time
time_str = time.localtime()

print(time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S AM", time_str))
```

Result:

```
05/06/2019 16:51:19
```

Comment: I believe the issue isn't formatting, but rather that he expected the `time` variable to always remain up-to-date with the current time.